# write a regex for javascript for repeating capture groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a format checker to check if the inputed argument is in correct format so I use regex

```js
function checkFormat(rcvString)
{
    let formatRegex = /(\s*?(\s*?[0-9]*\s*?,\s*?[0-9]*\s*?)\s*?),\1$/;
    return formatRegex.test(rcvString);
}
var str = "(35, 6), (   5,65) , (3,3 )"
console.log(checkFormat(str));
```

Variable `str` can have multiple capture groups and space are optional `"(35, 6), (   5,65) , (3,3 ) and so on"` but `formatRegex` isn't working

Answer (score 1):

You can't repeat capture groups using a quantifier because the buffer will only keep track of the last group matched.  But here is a corrected version of your regex:

```
let formatRegex = /\(\s*\d+\s*,\s*\d+\s*\)(?:\s*,\s*\(\s*\d+\s*,\s*\d+\s*\))*/;
return formatRegex.test(rcvString);
```

Here is a regex demo showing that the pattern works for your test input.

### Demo

The regex pattern basically just matches a single tuple in parentheses, followed by zero or more commas and another tuple.  Here is an explanation of the regex logic used for the first tuple (the rest of the pattern mostly just repeats this):

```
\(        match a (
    \s*   zero or more spaces
    \d+   a number
    \s*   zero or more spaces
    ,     a comma
    \s*   zero or more spaces
    \d+   the second number
    \s*   zero or more spaces
\)        match a (
```

Comment: so \s* means that it can have many whitespace or single space or none at all?